# How to get a value from textbox array element?

Tags: arrays, textbox, c++-cli

i did a textbox array and lets say if i want to take a value from array element textboxes[0] how should i write it(i mean the line where i set a value for sk)?I am really sorry guys i am wasting your time but I have no knowledge about user interface and just trying to learn something.Thanks a lot.
i did the following... .

so it should be like this?
i create and array of 10 textboxes?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        string sk;
array<TextBox ^, 1> ^ ar = gcnew array<TextBox ^, 1>(10);
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
 ar[i] = gcnew array<TextBox^,1>(10);
}
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: **1)** Always tag your questions with the language and framework you're using. I'm assuming this is C++/CLI, and have added that tag. **2)** Your title is useless - you should edit it to describe what your problem  is. **3)** I fixed your poor code formatting, and removed an extraneous `}; }` in the process. Please ensure it is correct, and try to only post valid code snippets in the future.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, thanks.

Comment: Do you really require a 10x10 array of `TextBox`es? Seems a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't actually created any `TextBox`es.

```
array<array<TextBox^,1>^>^ textBoxes = gcnew array<array<TextBox^,1>^>(10);
```

There you've created an array of 10 arrays of `TextBox`.

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    textBoxes[i] = gcnew array<TextBox^,1>(10);
}
```

And there you've created an array of 10 `TextBox`es for each element in `textBoxes`. So now you have an array of 10 arrays of ***references to*** `TextBox`, but you haven't actually created any `TextBox` instances yet.

The problem arises at this line:

```
sk = Double::Parse(textBoxes[0]->Text);
```

`textBoxes[0]` doesn't refer to a `TextBox`, it refers to an array of 10 `TextBoxes`.  The correct syntax might be `textBoxes[0][0]->Text`. But again, that reference is currently `null` because you haven't created an `TextBox`es yet.

Although kind of ridiculous, this code creates an array of 10 arrays of 10 `TextBoxes`, instantiating a `TextBox` for each, and filling in the `->Text` of each with an identifier.

```
private:
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    // An array of 10 arrays of `TextBox`
    array<array<TextBox^,1>^>^ textBoxes = gcnew array<array<TextBox^,1>^>(10);

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // Instantiate an array of 10 TextBoxes for each element
        textBoxes[i] = gcnew array<TextBox^,1>(10);

        for (int j=0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            // Create a TextBox instance for each element in the sub-array
            textBoxes[i][j] = gcnew TextBox();

            // Set its text to show its indices in the arrays
            textBoxes[i][j]->Text = String::Format("I am {0},{1}", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i have like 10 different textboxes lets say textbox1 textbox2...textbox10 and i want to read the values from them(that is what i am trying to do). How can i do this by loop? If you could just make a little example for me or pass any tutorial link i would be so thankful...

Comment: You don't. You have 10x10=100 textbox references.

Comment: ok i understand now.Just one more thing if i want to make    textboxes[0][0]=textbox1,....textboxes[4][0]=textbox4, how should i write my loop, i dont understand how to change textbox inder 1,2,3,4, i am thinking something like textboxes[i][0]=textbox(i+1), how to write this?

Comment: With one more array, this one manually initialized. But I don't know if the C++/CLI language supports an equivalent of the C# code `SomeClass[] someArray = new SomeClass[] { object1, object2, object3 };`